# Predicate logic proof

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Prove the following formula.

$$ \vdash (\exists x)(A \land B) \lor (\exists x)(A \land C) \equiv (\exists x)(A \land (B \lor C))$$
The question is number 10 in chapter 6 in "Mathematical Logic" by Tourlakis.

My try :

$$ (\exists x)(A \land B) \lor (\exists x)(A \land C) $$
$$ A \land (\exists x)B \lor A \land (\exists x)C $$
$$ A \land ((\exists x)B \lor (\exists x)C)$$

I got stuck in that step.

Comment: It's not true, the $\to$ direction fails.

Comment: I see now you have a typo in the firsr connective,you mean $\land$ instead of $\lor$. Start by distributing $\exists$ over $\lor$.

Comment: Which part exactly i have to do the distribution on ?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must follow Git Gud's answer and complete the proof with the formal details according to theorems and rules of your textbook.

We must use **6.1.7 Theorem**. (Distributivity of $\forall$ over $\land$) : $\vdash (\forall x)(A \land B) \equiv (\forall x) A \land (\forall x) B$, page 158.

Start with : $(\exists x)(A \land (B \lor C)$ and rewrite with $\forall$ :

> $\lnot (\forall x) \lnot (A \land (B \lor C))$

then use De Morgan : $\lnot (\forall x) (\lnot A \lor \lnot (B \lor C))$, De Morgan again : $\lnot (\forall x) (\lnot A \lor (\lnot B \land \lnot C))$, distribute : $\lnot (\forall x) ((\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \land (\lnot A \lor \lnot C))$, and De Morgan again : $\lnot [(\forall x) (\lnot (A \land B) \land \lnot (A \land C))]$.

Now we apply **Th 6.1.7** :

> $\lnot [(\forall x) \lnot (A \land B) \land (\forall x)\lnot (A \land C)]$.

Now, we "switch" again from $\forall$ to $\exists$ :

> $\lnot [\lnot (\exists x) (A \land B) \land \lnot (\exists x) (A \land C)]$.

Finally, we apply again De Morgan :

> $\lnot \lnot [(\exists x) (A \land B) \lor (\exists x) (A \land C)]$

and Double Negation :

> > $(\exists x) (A \land B) \lor (\exists x) (A \land C)$.

Comment: But we want to proof $ (\exists x)(A \land B) \lor (\exists x)(A \land C) $ not $ \land $.

Comment: When you applied de morgan before applying 6.1.7, you took the negation outside beside the quantifier. Can you really do that ? Iam confused

Comment: The external negation is never moved; until the last step (double negation) it stay in front of the complete formula.